# Reusing a Go channel causes deadlock

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I'm new to `golang` (whith `Java` concurrency background). Consider this peace of code :

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sendenum(num int, c chan int) {
    c <- num
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go sendenum(0, c)
    x, y := <-c, <-c
    fmt.Println(x, y)
}
```

When I run this code , I get this error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /home/tarrsalah/src/go/src/github.com/tarrsalah/stackoverflow/chan_dead_lock.go:12 +0x90
exit status 2
```

I know, adding another `go sendenum(0, c)` statement fix the issue, ... but

**When** and **Where** the deadlock happened ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After it receives the 0, `main` keeps on waiting on the receiving end of `c` for another value to arrive (to put in the `y` variable), but it never will, as the goroutine running `main` is the only one left to live.

When you add another `go sendenum(0, c)`, it actually gets a value on the second channel receive, puts it into the `y` variable, prints `x` and `y` out and the program finishes succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that "reusing" a channel is a problem. It's just a simple deadlock happening because the code prescribes two reads, but only one write to the same channel. The second read can never happen, hence the deadlock.